# How to convert a date string in one format to a string in another format (one with a timezone offset)?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date in string format, e.g. `2020-01-10`.  What's the proper vanilla JS way to convert this to a string in this format--one with a time and time zone offset, e.g.

`2020-01-10T00:00-0500`

In my case, the time will always be midnight, and the offset will always be -0500.

I guess I can start by creating a new date object from my string, like so:

```
dateString = `2020-01-10`;
dateObj = new Date(dateString);
```

But then what?

Using [dateObj.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) on my new date object looks to get me close. This will output a string with the desired date and time, but not the desired timezone offset:

`2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z`

Would I have to then use additional string methods to insert my desired timezone offset (e.g. `dateObj.toISOString(dateObj).slice(0,23)+'-05:00'`)?  Or can I perhaps create the initial date object with this timezone offset already in-place?

I am aware of libraries to assist with this (e.g. momentjs).  But I am hoping for a vanilla JS solution, if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your timezone offset (-5h) the local timezone or do you want to force this offset ?

Comment: I want to force this offset in all cases.

Comment: `Date` objects don't have a timezone.
If you're targeting only recent browsers, [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
moment([2016, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]).utcOffset(-5, true) // Equivalent to "2016-01-01T00:00:00-05:00"
```

Although my answer may not be precise but it can be useful for you and i request you to go for momemt.js docs for further clarification